Manipulating specific columns in a csv via Bash?
I am writing a script to setup a csv file with data parsed from another .txt file. I have a few particular columns, and how this program flows, I am using these columns to grab data from the .txt. I am just unsure on how to proceed, since I want the next column to be tied to the current iteration of things Im looking at.
The general code I have is like this:
#!/bin/bash 
COLUMNS=(1 2 3) 

for column in "${COLUMNS[@]}"; do
   echo "${COLUMNS[@]}" > someCSVFile.csv
   parsedText=$(sed -n '/'$column-'/,/^${/^$/d; p}' someTextFile.txt)
   for line in "${parsedText[@]}"; do
      echo "${line}" >> someCSVFile.csv
   done
done 

When I parse the code, The text returns in a format like:
a
b
c

For sake of example, lets assume COLUMN 1 returns "abc" (in the format above), COLUMN 2 returns "def", and so on. Ideally, I should pass to the CSV in the second for loop which should be like:
1,2,3
a,d,g
b,e,h
c,f,i

But instead, the output will be:
1
a
b
c
2
d
e
f
3
g
h
i

Is there a way, based on iteration of the loop, that I can move to the next column of the csv?

parsedText is NOT an array. parsedText =  is not valid bash (NO ' ' spaces around '=' sign allowed). Before posting here (or now and edit questions with results) paste your script into ShellCheck and fix warning/errors (wonderful tool). That's to start. Then you likely can do this all in a single call to awk. Show your actual input rather than COLUMNS=(1 2 3) (which I take as a quick example) and explain the logic that takes 1 2 3 and converts that into a heading of "1,1,1" with lines that follows "a,a,a", "b,b,b", etc..

@DavidC.Rankin Apologies. New to bash and new to posting here. Question has been edited.

I agree with David, this kind of thing is much easier with awk.

You can do what you want in bash, but it is somewhat inflexible. The logic is a bit strained since output is line-oriented, but your logic is column-oriented. But still, bash is quite capable and can put round-pegs in square-holes.
Basically you want to loop 1-3 and then index letters 0, 2, 5 (e.g. "a,d,g") for the first row, then index letters 1, 3, 6 for the second, and so on.
You can create the array of letters using a simple brace expansion, e.g. letters=( {a..z} ), and then just loop over your original array for 1,2,3. Putting that altogether you can do:
#!/bin/bash

cols=(1 2 3)          # your example
letters=( {a..z} )    # fill array with a-z using brace expansion

str="${cols[*]}"      # convert array to string of space separated values
echo "${str// /,}"    # echo to stdout with commas

## loop 1-3 and output corresponding letter desired using indexes
for c in "${cols[@]}"; do
  echo "${letters[c-1]},${letters[c+2]},${letters[c+5]}"
done

(note: do not use UPPERCASE variable names, those are generally reserved for bash system variables and the environment)
Example Use/Output
With the script in cols.sh you would get:
$ bash cols.sh
1,2,3
a,d,g
b,e,h
c,f,i

You can redirect it all to a file with bash cols.sh > somefile.
Let me know if you have further questions.
(edited to add commas)
(2nd edit to eliminate call to sed, instead using built-in parameter expansion with substring replacement)
